# Проблема с TerminateThread

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Создаю поток.

```
connect = new thread(&startWaitConnect,this);
connect->detach();
```

Потом вызываю `connect->native_handle()` и получаю 0. `TerminateThread((HANDLE) connect->native_handle(), 0)` возвращает ошибку 6. При этом сам native_handle возвращает long long а не HANDLE. Приходиться выполнять приведение типа. Это нормально?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вызываемый вами метод [`detach()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) передает владение потоком самому потоку. После команды `detach`  никакие команды потоку вы отдавать уже не можете, потому что он может (потенциально) уже завершиться.

Если вы собираетесь как-то управлять потоком - не используйте `detach`.

---

PS `TerminateThread` - это очень плохая идея, завершенный таким образом поток оставит много незакрытых ресурсов и мусора в памяти. Лучше придумайте способ кооперативного завершения.

Например, если поток работает с сокетом - то можно закрыть этот сокет.

Comment: А что лучше использовать? Например в java есть start

Comment: @Andru причем тут вообще start?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то `native_handle()` возвращает `native_handle_type` - тип, зависящий от реализации. Например, в VC++ это

```
typedef void *native_handle_type;
```

и точно так же определен тип

```
typedef void *HANDLE;
```

Так что если вам приходится использовать приведение типа, то это недоработка компилятора.

Но это в вашем случае, увы, не играет особой роли, так как, поскольку вам возвращается значение 0, похоже, `native_handle()` не возвращает *корректный* дескриптор (возможно, поток уже завершился?). В стандарте сказано

**30.2.3 Native handles [thread.req.native]**
*Several classes described in this Clause have members `native_handle_type` and `native_handle`. The
presence of these members and their semantics is implementation-defined. [ Note: These members allow
implementations to provide access to implementation details. Their names are specified to facilitate portable
compile-time detection. Actual use of these members is inherently non-portable. —end note ]*

то есть все зависит от вашего конкретного компилятора. Так что вам нужно обратиться к его документации по поводу приведения типа. Допускаю даже, что не слишком умный компилятор мог сделать просто "затычку", всегда возвращающую нуль :) - но это вряд ли...

Далее, я бы сказал, что смешивать использование API для работы с потоками и стандартные функции - не слишком-то хорошо. Или дожидайтесь окончания с помощью `join()`, или вообще забудьте о потоке - для этого, собственно, и служит `detach()`. Для чего вам заставлять форсированно завершаться отключенный поток (фактически не позволяя выполнить все очищающие процедуры)? Что вы хотите этим добиться? Почему этого нельзя добиться средствами стандарта?